# How to use div classes to get my blocks to line up?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website for my assignment for university. My teacher told me to use div classes so that my CSS code will be reduced but here are the problems. I have div class for images and they are supposed to be next to each other in a same row.

I have another 3 div class boxes for text which should be below divs with images, and also I have 2 background images one of them should be on left hand side and other one on right so it creates a flag of Italy. I have tried everything I can thing of but I still cannot make it work properly. Can anyone help?

[This is what I want to achieve roughly](http://filedropper.com/fail)

http://jsfiddle.net/p2uwm8ye/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- This is standard HTML code that tells the browser it is a HTML page-->
<html lang="en-GB"> <!-- This tells the browser what language html is using-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
    <title>Main Page</title> <!-- This is a code that displays title of the page-->
</head>
<body>
<header id="pageHeader"><!-- This header tag is used to create a navigation bar-->
    <nav id="site"><!-- This is a navigation tag which allows to link different webpages together-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/tables.html">Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/forms.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/text.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/references.html">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/validation.html">Validation</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </nav>
</header>
    <div id="welcome"><!-- This is a div tag that is used to create a welcome message on my website-->
    <h1>Papa Italiano</h1>
</div>
            <div class="images"><!-- This div class I have used to put three images using just one piece of css code which reduced the code-->
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image11.jpg" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 1</figcaption>  
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image22.jpg" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image32.jpg" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
            <div class="text"></div><!-- similar to div class for images however this is for text-->
            <div class="text"></div>
            <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="clearing"></div><!-- this div class is basically making sure that my other div classes will not go into each other-->
</div>
        <div id="background">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/background1.jpg" alt="background photo" />
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="background2">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/background2.jpg" alt="background photo" />
            </figure>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css

```
header#pageHeader{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}/* this is my css for a navigation bar*/
nav#site li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    width:160px;
}/*This is used to style my links*/
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF0;
}/* This is used to style look of the links*/
.images{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}/*This is telling my all div class images how they need to be styled*/
#welcome{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px; 
    font: arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}/*This is telling browser how to style my div welcome*/
.text{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}/*Similar to .images however this piece of codes is used for my text*/
#background{
    height: 80px;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0px;
}
#background2{
    height: 80px;
    width: 250px;
    right: 0px;
}
.clearing{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and put your code there, then update the question.

Comment: to indent your code on here to then post it, highlight it and press ctrl+k

Comment: ok I got the code how about the pictures? do you need those? and thanks for telling me how to do the code  haha

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want to achieve please? That will help!

Comment: well I do not have an exact picture but below papa italiana that is name of the website I want to have all my 3 images in inline-block next to each other, below that pictures i want another 3 boxes for text which will be parallel with the image box and on top of these boxes I will have a background image that will be behind them @Pipo obviously that design can change if you got better idea ;D

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/fail obviously these green and red boxes need to go behind the content as they will be performing a background image @Pipo

Comment: Background images should be in your CSS as... `background-image: url()` and the element having them as background image could be body or #welcome, I didn't look thoroughly. Is there a reason this isn't the case?

Comment: I would normally do it in css with background-image however this background is basically 2 rows one is green one is red where red should be on right hand side of the page and green one should be on left hand side of the page so I basically made another div class for them. But that still doesn't fix the issue with my div being messed up

Comment: Ok so I have did use your advice but I made div id just for the background itself and then added css to it so that it does what I want, I also used z-index: -1; so that it goes behind the content now the only issue left is I have all div classes in 1 row and I want to have 1 row of images which are 3 boxes and then 2nd row below images for text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood everything you wanted but that might help you. To improve your coding skills you should learn more about:

- The **box model** in css: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/
- Always try to **simplify your code** as much as possible and don't use `id` or `class` if you don't need to.
- **Learn differences** between `position: relative` and `position: absolute` and when to use them: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/
- **Make sure you understand the natural flow of css and html, this is what you should start with.**

Study the following code and play with it to better understand how things work together. Good luck and have fun learning!

**SOLUTION 1 (inline-block hack with `<!--`)**

```css
#pageHeader {
    background-color: grey;
    /* As there is nothing behind your #pageHeader, it is better to choose a grey color with no opacity */
    min-height: 80px;
}
nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* This code will center your navigation bar. The 90% width will give it space. */
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16.6666666%;
    /* 100% (full-width) / 6 (as you have 6 elements in your nav bar) */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF0;
}
nav a:hover {
    /* always define a style for your links when they are hovered. This is a suggestion of style. */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.main { /* This is for your italian flag in the background. If you need to support more browser just use a compress image instead. Note that this code is not cross-browser, check required code on Mozilla Developer Network */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
}
.wrapper {
    /* you wrap your main elements so that you don't have to reproduce this style every time */
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font: arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: green;
    padding: 20px 0 75px;
    margin: 0;
}
.images {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    /* 100% / 3 images per row */
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.images figure {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
figure figcaption, figure p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li><!-- 
            --><li><a href="html/tables.html">Tables</a></li><!-- 
            --><li><a href="html/forms.html">Feedback</a></li><!-- 
            --><li><a href="html/text.html">About Us</a></li><!-- 
            --><li><a href="html/references.html">References</a></li><!-- 
            --><li><a href="html/validation.html">Validation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <h1>Papa Italiano</h1>

        <div class="images">
            <!-- This div class I have used to put three images using just one piece of css code which reduced the code-->
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 1</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 2</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 3</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**SOLUTION 2 (inline-block hack with `margin-right: -4px;`)**

```css
#pageHeader {
    background-color: grey;
    /* As there is nothing behind your #pageHeader, it is better to choose a grey color with no opacity */
    min-height: 80px;
}
nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* This code will center your navigation bar. The 90% width will give it space. */
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16.6666666%;
    /* 100% (full-width) / 6 (as you have 6 elements in your nav bar) */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -4px; /* 2nd trick to remove space between inline-blocks) */
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF0;
}
nav a:hover {
    /* always define a style for your links when they are hovered. This is a suggestion of style. */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.main { /* This is for your italian flag in the background. If you need to support more browser just use a compress image instead. Note that this code is not cross-browser, check required code on Mozilla Developer Network */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
}
.wrapper {
    /* you wrap your main elements so that you don't have to reproduce this style every time */
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font: arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: green;
    padding: 20px 0 75px;
    margin: 0;
}
.images {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    /* 100% / 3 images per row */
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.images figure {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
figure figcaption, figure p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/tables.html">Tables</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/forms.html">Feedback</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/text.html">About Us</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/references.html">References</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/validation.html">Validation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <h1>Papa Italiano</h1>

        <div class="images">
            <!-- This div class I have used to put three images using just one piece of css code which reduced the code-->
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 1</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 2</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 3</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**SOLUTION 3 (just use `floated block` elements)**

```css
#pageHeader {
    background-color: grey;
    /* As there is nothing behind your #pageHeader, it is better to choose a grey color with no opacity */
    min-height: 80px;
}
nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* This code will center your navigation bar. The 90% width will give it space. */
}
nav:after { /* To clear elements after the nav. As you use floated li you have to clear after) */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {
    float: left; /* Third way to align li elements */
    width: 16.6666666%;
    /* 100% (full-width) / 6 (as you have 6 elements in your nav bar) */
    text-align: center;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF0;
}
nav a:hover {
    /* always define a style for your links when they are hovered. This is a suggestion of style. */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.main { /* This is for your italian flag in the background. If you need to support more browser just use a compress image instead. Note that this code is not cross-browser, check required code on Mozilla Developer Network */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 33%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, red 66%, red 100%);
}
.wrapper {
    /* you wrap your main elements so that you don't have to reproduce this style every time */
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font: arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: green;
    padding: 20px 0 75px;
    margin: 0;
}
.images {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    /* 100% / 3 images per row */
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.images figure {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
figure figcaption, figure p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/tables.html">Tables</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/forms.html">Feedback</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/text.html">About Us</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/references.html">References</a></li> 
            <li><a href="html/validation.html">Validation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <h1>Papa Italiano</h1>

        <div class="images">
            <!-- This div class I have used to put three images using just one piece of css code which reduced the code-->
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 1</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 2</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/food" alt="photo" />
                <figcaption>Food 3</figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: WoW! This is brilliant even better than what I wanted to achieve. I thought I am pretty good at html and css but what you did is amazing, I will study my orginal code and yours and see how you simplified the code, thank you for your time and effort that you have put into this.

Comment: No worries mate ;)! Have fun with your project!

Comment: I have a specific requirement that says: Pages should be viewable on monitors with screen resolutions of 1024 × 768 without users 
having to scroll horizontally. Is there a way to make a page scale according to users screen resolution?

Comment: The solution I gave you is called `responsive` which means that you will never have to scroll horizontally (copy my code in a fiddle and then resize your browser window to check how elements resize). Check my css for width in `%`. Using percentage units on your website skeleton will make sure that your website will follow your clients screen size. You can learn more about responsive web design here: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: You are a star, I have figured it might be the width in % that is making it to resize. I thought I know everything but now I feel like I don't know anything haha

Comment: There is 1 more thing that seems I don't understand in your css code under nav li{ you have put width: 16.6666666% as I have 6 elements, and then you have put text-align: center and vertical in middle however these 6 links do not fit into 1 line and there are not in the middle either, is that an issue with google chrome?

Comment: And also I would like to impress my teacher and make my page accessible for blind people so when they are using keyboard and when they press tab they skip straight into a content which would be a first picture. any clue where i can look for that?

Comment: It's important to understand that the `nav li` are `inline-block`, which means that, **as block elements** you can center a text inside each block with `text-align: center;` (center vertically) and **as inline elements** you align all elements on the same line (horizontally center). This is why I added both. Try changing or removing `text-align: center;` or `vertical-align: middle;` to see how centering is changing.

Comment: There is also a trick to make sure that all `inline-block` elements are on the same line. As you might know, inline-block elements have a small margin of 4 px that is added by every browser. To avoid that be sure to comment the end of each `</li>` with `<!--` and to comment out the beginning of each `<li>` with `-->`. Check the code snippet in my answer for reference.

Comment: Concerning accessibility it is truly a big thing to master but you can start with the following article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/21/mobile-accessibility-why-care-what-can-you-do/?utm_content=bufferafc89&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer and then find everything you need on the MDN website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility

Comment: when I delete any of the aligns it doesn't change anything I have also added <!-- --> just as you have on your example still doesn't change it, and it's not centered on your example either

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle to play with (easier to resize window): http://jsfiddle.net/6x9rt9k4/. What browser are you using? Do all the `li` display on the same line for you?

Comment: I am using google chrome but it needs to work correctly on chrome and firefox for my assignment and no the last link is on a new line, and they are not centered as I said

Comment: I have updated my answer with two other ways of aligning inline elements. Try solution 2 or 3 if the first one doesn't work for you. Both solution should be working in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That worked fine. my lecturer said that this is a good start and i will get about 70% but if I want more I need to add more html and css features, I have used tables and forms. thinking of adding some animation to images and some accessibility for blind user to boost my grade, any other ideas?